# How do I backup /var/log to my home directory?

Tags: command-line

I need to create a script to backs up the entire content of /var/log into my home directory. The output folder name should be auto-generated in ~/backups/logYYYYMMDD format.

Comment: What have you already tried? Where did you fail?

Comment: Crosspost: http://askubuntu.com/questions/690510/how-do-i-backup-var-log-to-my-home-directory

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do so is to generate a gzipped tarball:

```
#!/bin/bash

tar cvzf ~/backups/log`date +"%Y%m%d"`/backup.tar.gz /var/log
```

Comment: Why use back-ticks instead of `$()` for the date command substitution?  I think backticks are harder to read and more error prone.  Also, why specify bash when /bin/sh will do?

Comment: @RobertL That's more or less the same. You can use the alternative if you prefer. `$()` is easier to read than backticks when nesting; in this case won't make much of a difference.